# DirectX11 buffer for generated 2D map

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am working on simple 2D game (pacman like).
Map for game is made of tiles (2D array 30x40), each tile is represented by 16px x 16px graphic.
My problem is that I  redraw all tiles (30x40 = 1200 tiles) each frame which makes FPS pretty low.
My idea to solve this is to draw map (1200 tiles) to one big buffer, then each frame draw only this buffer, but I do not know how to achieve that, this is my first project with DirectX.
How to achieve that or maybe you have better idea.

Code (simplified):

```
ID3D11Device* pDevice;
ID3D11DeviceContext* pImmediateContext;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRenderTargetView;
IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain;
ID3D11Resource* pResource;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* pTexture;
std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SpriteBatch> spriteBatch;
Game* pGame;
```

Function used to render frame

```
void GameApp::renderGame(float dt) {
    pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(pRenderTargetView, DirectX::Colors::Black);
    spriteBatch->Begin();
    pGame->draw();
    spriteBatch->End();
    pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

pGame->draw();

```
void Game::draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeX; ++j) {
            // Draw tile
            spriteBatch->Draw(pTexture, vPosition, &sourceRect, tint, rotation, vOrigin, vScale,
            DirectX::SpriteEffects::SpriteEffects_None, 0.0f);
            tile->Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Function I use to load sprites (I call it once, not in loop)

```
DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFile(device, file, &pResource, &pTexture)
```

Tell me if you need more detail.

Comment: Are you loading the texture from file in each frame? Then this is what's making your application slow.

Comment: Of course not, I load each kind of tile (10 *.dds files) once.

Comment: Then why is there a `CreateDDSTextureFromFile()` call in your `draw()` method?

Comment: ``DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFile(device, file, &pResource, &pTexture)`` in the ``Draw`` method does indeed look like the problem :) You should be able to draw a few thousand sprites pretty fast. As it is, you are loading and creating a new texture every frame which is going to be slow, especially when you turn around and draw the same texture right after loading which means it has to block until the GPU is done processing the texture load. BTW, instead of using raw pointers for your Direct3D COM objects, consider using [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

Comment: Oh, sorry. That is mistake I made while simplified code for stackoverflow question. As I said earlier, I load 10 *.dds files only once. Fixed question.

Comment: Ok, so you want to render your map to texture then. Have you searched for some articles about that? There are actually a lot of resources that describe exactly what you need.

Comment: I think you are right, render all tiles into single texture then just draw that texture would solve problem. I made research for tutorial how to do that, but couldn't find solution, this is my first project with DirectX and I feel confused. Do you have sample code/article/tutorial about it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to render to a single texture. This would fly on a modern computer. Can you show us the Draw method for the tile?

Comment: What should I do then instead? Draw method is already in question `spriteBatch->Draw(pTexture, vPosition, &sourceRect, tint, rotation, vOrigin, vScale, DirectX::SpriteEffects::SpriteEffects_None, 0.0f);`
SpriteBatch is class from DirectXTK (DirectX tool kit)